# Using event in both managed and unmanaged code

Tags: c++, events, visual-studio-2017, clr, managed-c++

I had mostly worked on unmanaged code, recently for my work I have to use CLI/C++ projects. Some of the files are unmanaged code, so while including I use `#pragma managed(push, off)`
I had seen in full unmanaged codes we have been using event and deligate in Ref classes.

```
event someHandler^ someEvent;
public delegate void someHandler(ManagedCpp::sharedPtr<std::string> ^);
```

But now I need to create the same kind of mechanism for a mixture of managed and unmanaged. So as I was making that Model view class as managed, I am unable to include it in unmanaged Class.

**Managed class where I will be defiing the event(s) and delegate...**

```
public delegate void someHandler(ManagedCpp::sharedPtr<std::string> ^);
    class ModelView{
       managedCpp::sharedPtr ^ memberPtr
     public:
       event someHandler^ someEvent;
       ModelView(){
          memberPtr= gcnew managedCpp::sharedPtr<std::string>
       }
       //some other functions
       // a getter() to get the memberPtr
       // a setter() to set the value of memberPtr
    }
```

So I need to include this class in others classes of which some are managed and others are unmanaged.

When I include in managed class it throws error.

```
error C3821: 'memberPtr': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function
```

Could anyone please help me how I can resolve this encountered issue?